# GPU not recognised?

Tags: motherboard, gpu

Recently I tried to change the GPU on my pc (nothing was wrong with it worked fine) to a spare GPU that I had that was far better. The spare GPU turned out to be faulty. When I tried to reconnect the old GPU my monitor comes up with 'no input'. I have a Gigabyte GV-RX6UP128DE graphics card and an Asus M2N-E motherboard running windows 7.

Comment: Did you remember to connect the power cables to the graphics card?

Comment: @Paul I have never connected a power cable to the graphics card?? Even when it did work

Answer (score 1):

Does it POST at all?
With that Asus board you should look out for the following POST codes in particular:

- One Short (VGA card test OK)
- One Long Three Short (Cannot detect any VGA card or VGA card test fail)

If you have further PCI slots available try installing the card into them or try reinstalling the card in the same slot. Ensure the golden finger on the card is clean and undamaged also check there is nothing in the slot itself.

Sorry for posting an answer not a comment, I cannot post comments with such low reputation.

Best of luck